# Shared memory performing worse

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I am performing Sobel edge detection with a horizontal mask of size 3x3 and a vertical mask of size 3x3.

I first implemented the algorithm without using shared memory and now I tried implementing it using shared memory. The performance when shared memory was not used is better than when it was.

Can anybody explain this observation please?

Code:

```
__global__ void image(int * in, int *out, int width){
    int Mx[3][3] = {{-1,0,1},{-2,0,2},{-1,0,1}};
    int My[3][3] = {{1,2,1},{0,0,0},{-1,-2,-1}};
    __shared__ int sIn[t][t];
    int sumX = 0, sumY = 0;

    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    int r = threadIdx.y;
    int c = threadIdx.x;
    sIn[r][c] = in[(row*width) + col];
    __syncthreads();

    if(row == 0 || row == width-1 || col == 0 || col == width-1){
        out[row*width + col] = 0;
    }else{
        for(int i = -1; i < 2; i++){
            for(int j = -1; j < 2; j++){
                int pixel;
                if(r == 0 || r == (t-1) || c == 0 || c == (t-1))
                    pixel = in[(row + i) * width + (col + j)];
                else
                    pixel = sIn[r + i][c + j];
                sumX += pixel * Mx[i+1][j+1];
                sumY += pixel * My[i+1][j+1];
            }
        }
        int ans = abs(sumX) + abs(sumY);
        if(ans > 255) ans = 255;
        if(ans < 0) ans = 0;
        out[row*width + col] = ans;
    }
}
```

`t` is the tile size.

Kernel call:

```
image<<<dim3(width/t, width/t, 1),dim3(t, t, 1)>>>(d_input, d_output, width);
```

Comment: Why should that kernel be faster with shared memory?

Comment: less global memory accesses

Comment: You want someone to explain to you why a code you **have** shown is better or worse than some other code you **have not** shown?

Comment: I got it... I needed to use extra tiles to store apron pixels

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I used apron pixels thus increasing the tile width so as to reduce global memory accesses when the 3x3 mask's boundary pixels were checked